# Keras Nan accuracy and loss after first training step

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, nan

I have a classification task on temporal data. My training loss is 0 or Nan from the first epoch, and the accuracy always Nan, even with a very small learning rate.

My model :

```
def FCN():
    """
    Keras fully convolutional model to predict lead inversion.

    Inspired by solution found here : https://github.com/Bsingstad/FYS-STK4155-oblig3
    """
    inputlayer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(N_MEASURES, N_LEADS))

    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, input_shape=(N_MEASURES, N_LEADS),
                                padding='same')(inputlayer)
    # conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.Activation(activation='relu')(conv1)

    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding='same')(conv1)
    # conv2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv2)

    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(conv2)
    # conv3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv3)

    gap_layer = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv3)

    outputlayer = tf.squeeze(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(gap_layer), axis=-1)


    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputlayer, outputs=outputlayer)

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0000000000000000000001, clipnorm=1), 
                  metrics=[
                      tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy', dtype=None, threshold=0.5),
                  ])

    return model
```

Training loop :

```
train_data_gen = ECGDataGenerator(train_input[train][0:4], train_output[train][0:4],
                                  batch_size=4,
                                  shuffle=True)
val_data_gen = train_data_gen

model = FCN()
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_data_gen):
    if i > 0:
        break
    y_pred = model.predict(x)
    print(x.shape)
    print(y)
    print(y_pred)
    print(y_pred.shape)
    loss = model.loss(y, y_pred)
    print(loss)

model.fit(x=train_data_gen,
          epochs=2,
          steps_per_epoch=2,
          # steps_per_epoch=train_data_gen.n_batches,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          verbose=1,
          validation_freq=1,
          #               callbacks=[reduce_lr,early_stop]
          )

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_data_gen):
    if i > 10:
        break
    y_pred = model.predict(x)
    print(x.shape)
    print(y)
    print(y_pred)
    print(y_pred.shape)
    loss = model.loss(y, y_pred)
    print(loss)
```

The output is as following :

```
(4, 2500, 12)
[0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0.50108045 0.5034382  0.4999477  0.5007813 ]
(4,)
tf.Tensor(0.6949963, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Epoch 1/2
2/2 [==============================] - 3s 794ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: nan - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: nan
Epoch 2/2
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 283ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: nan - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: nan
(4, 2500, 12)
[1. 0. 0. 1.]
[nan nan nan nan]
(4,)
tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

As you can see, the training loss and accuracy are 0 or Nan after one training step, although the loss is not Nan if we compute it manually just before training.

Batch size here is 4.

Things I've tried :

- Adding batch normalization does not help.
- Removing GlobalAveragePooling1D solves the Nan problem but gives shape issues.
- Reducing / augmenting learning rate does the same.
- Input and output do not contain Nan values

Comment: And that extremely low learning rate?. Have you tried with 0.01 as lr?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez yes I have, it does the same thing. The low LR is just me trying to make sure that it is not too high, to eliminate a possibility. I  have also tried other optimizers, with no more success

Comment: Why do you use `tf.squeeze()`  in the last layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually an error with my custom data generator that returned the number of data entries instead of the number of batches per epoch on `__len__()`